# Как отправить пару байт на сервер, используя си?

Tags: c, сокет

помогите! только начинаю на си кодить, перешёл на сокеты. 
надо всего лишь отправить 0xFE01 на сервер и прочитать ответ, а прога выдаёт segfault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int socket_connect(char *host, in_port_t port){
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int on = 1, sock;    
    printf("Resolving hostname...\n");
    if((hp = gethostbyname(host)) == NULL){
        herror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("ok\n");
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, &addr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (const char *)&on, sizeof(int));

    if(sock == -1){
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1){
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);

    }
    return sock;
}

void sendToServer(int sock) {
    uint16_t value = 0xFE01;
    char lo = value & 0xFF;
    char hi = value >> 8;

    char toSend[128];
    strcpy(toSend, lo);
    strcat(toSend, hi);
    printf("debug\n");
    if (write(sock, toSend, strlen(toSend)) < 0) {
        printf("Got error while sending data (byte)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd, n;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <hostname> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fd = socket_connect(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    printf("Connecting...done\n");
    printf("Writing data\n");
    sendToServer(fd);
    bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("done. Reading anwser\n");

    n = read(fd, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    printf("Goodbye\n");
    shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример кода сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcpy(toSend, lo);
strcat(toSend, hi);
```

у strcpy и strcat оба параметра char *, а тут  char * и просто один символ char. Это разные вещи. Присвоение может быть

```
toSend[0] = lo
```

и т.д